# Tag Wiki editing

Tags: discussion, tags

My suggestion for the advaita tag wiki "Is the belief in the non-duality of the Atman and the Brahman" got rejected (it isn't probably the best explanation and I am not complaining). But it now reads "Literally non-duality; a school of the Vedanta philosophy that declares the oneness of God, soul, and the universe."
If the tag is advaita, then why should the explanation talk about Advaita Vedanta, the school of Vedanta? Wouldn't it be more informative to have a separate tag called advaita-vedanta and edit the tag wiki of advaita?

Comment: Advaita and Advaita Vedanta are the same thing; it's not like there are Advaitins who reject the Brahma Sutras.  I can't think of a question which Advaita would apply to but Advaita-Vedanta would not, or vice versa.

Comment: Though I am not fully convinced, it does make sense to not have two tags. Thank you.